# Webサービスでonsenuiを使いたいのですが、buildするとcssが適用されません。

Tags: monaca, onsen-ui, angularjs

monacaでアプリ制作が一段落ついたので、アプリと連携したブラウザで動くWebサービスを開発しようとしています。
Webサプリのひな形はyeoman-angularで作成し、

```
bower install onsenui --save
```

としonsenuiをダウンロードし、index.htmlでonsenui.jsとonsenui.cssとonsen-css-components.cssをインクルードしました。その後モジュールの追加をしました。

```
   angular
      .module('confit1App', [         
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch',
　　　　 'onsen.directives'
      ])
```

ここまできてindex.htmlに

```
<ons-sliding-menu main-page="views/main.html" menu-page="views/menu.html" max-slide-distance="300px" type="push" var="app.menu">
</ons-sliding-menu>
```

とし、main.htmlにナビゲーションバーを追加しました。

```
grunt serve
```

としクロームで確認すると何の問題もなく表示、動作するのですが、デプロイするために

```
grunt build
grunt serve:dist
```

としプロダクション状態をクロームでに確認すると、スライディングメニュー自体は動くのですが（ドラッグすると右へページがスライドする。）肝心のナビゲーションバーが表示されません。
これはgruntのminifyのせいなのでしょうか。
だとしたら、公式ブログが記述しているようにgulpでやった方がいいのでしょうか？
（http://blog.asial.co.jp/1370）
yeoman-angularとonsenuiを使ってWebアプリを作ったことがある方や、何か分かる人アドバイスお願いします。